# Bad practice to use SQL Server's GOTO for error handling?

Tags: sql, sql-server, error-handling, goto

I was reading about error handling in SQL Server in [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/4451/SQL-Server-Transactions-and-Error-Handling), and they suggest using SQL Server's GOTO in certain situations to roll back the transaction.  Example:

```
BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE Authors
    SET Phone = '415 354-9866'
    WHERE au_id = '724-80-9391'

    SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM

    UPDATE Publishers
    SET city = 'Calcutta', country = 'India'
    WHERE pub_id = '9999'

    SELECT @intErrorCode = @@ERROR
    IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) GOTO PROBLEM
COMMIT TRAN

PROBLEM:
IF (@intErrorCode <> 0) BEGIN
PRINT 'Unexpected error occurred!'
    ROLLBACK TRAN
END
```

This article was written nearly 10 years ago and I've heard that it's usually a bad idea to use GOTO.  Is the above an ok method for error handling in SQL Server?  If not, can anyone suggest a better alternative?

Comment: Did you check this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11153012/1451723)?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should be using [Try/Catch](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx) in SQL 2005+

```
BEGIN TRY
    BEGIN TRAN

    UPDATE Authors
    SET Phone = '415 354-9866'
    WHERE au_id = '724-80-9391'

    UPDATE Publishers
    SET city = 'Calcutta', country = 'India'
    WHERE pub_id = '9999'

    COMMIT TRAN        
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
    PRINT 'Unexpected error occurred!'
    IF XACT_STATE() <> 0
        ROLLBACK TRAN    
END CATCH
```

Comment: In catch, print `ERROR_MESSAGE()`

Comment: if XACT_STATE is 1, we can still commit the transaction if wanted. If -1, always rollback

Answer (score 8):

You must incorporate `SET XACT_ABORT ON` in `Exception handling`

```
Begin Try
SET XACT_ABORT ON

BEGIN TRAN
    UPDATE Authors
    SET Phone = '415 354-9866'
    WHERE au_id = '724-80-9391'

    UPDATE Publishers
    SET city = 'Calcutta', country = 'India'
    WHERE pub_id = '9999'
COMMIT TRAN

End Try

Begin Catch
    Rollback Tran
End Catch
```